# Double-Checked Locking without creating objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm using Double-Checked Locking (DCL) to avoid the need of synchronization on an object if not needed to do so. In my case I need to synchronize when some buffer is empty, to have the "processing thread" to wait for the "delivery thread" to notify it again - otherwise, the "processing thread" will run in loops without doing something useful.

Both threads share these objects:

```
Object bufferLock = new Object();
Queue<Command> commands = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(); // thread safe!
```

Thread 1 ("delivery thread" - fills the buffer):

```
while (true)
    Command command = readCommand();
    commands.add(command);
    synchronize (bufferLock){
        bufferLock.notify(); // wake up Thread 2 (if waiting)
    }
}
```

Thread 2 ("processing thread" - empties the buffer):

```
while (true){
    if (commands.peek() == null){ // not creating anything here
        synchronized (bufferLock){
            if (commands.peek() == null){ // also not creating anything
                bufferLock.wait();
            }
        }
    }
    Command command = commands.poll();
    processCommand(command);
}
```

Now, NetBeans is showing up a warning about DCL, which made me dig into the subject deeper because the concept of DCL was unknown to me - I just started to use it on my own.

As far as I understand from reading several articles on the internet, there was a Java bug when using this pattern, but all examples use it in combination with lazy loading. In these examples, objects are created within the synchronized block. In my synchronized code, I do not create objects.

Is my code unsafe? Is NetBeans correct in showing a warning? Note that NetBeans had a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153334) related to DCL before, so I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: How does this compared this to using the built in Executor?  This wraps up a thread pool (can be one) and Queue of Runnable to run.  I would only write your own if you are confident it is better than the built in library to do much the same thing ;)

Comment: Another point: you seem to be reinventing the blocking operations already implemented for the queue. Why?

Comment: Doesn't the java bug with DCL have to do with object creation only (in  the singleton pattern)?

Comment: @Heuster Yes, this is definitely false alarm with respect to DCL.

Comment: DCL is useful when performing compound operations, like check-then-act operation is compound one used in singleton. There can be other uses of DCL too.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik A `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does not block if empty - it returns `null` then. The object lock is there only for the purpose to halt the processing thread. Note that I do not perform `add()`, `peek()` and `poll()` in synchronized blocks.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik OK so NetBeans would be wrong here? Probably because I'm checking two times on `null`, yet I don't create anything.

Comment: You *do* have the option to use `LinkedBlockingQueue`. NetBeans probably detects the pattern `if (someCondition) synchronized (x) { if (theSameConditionAgain) ... }`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for the link, I'll read the Concurrent package docs again carefully if something matches my situation. However I shouldn't create threads over and over again - processing should not be executed in parallel.

Comment: You can use a single-threaded `Executor`, no problem.

Comment: +1 Marko  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `LinkedBlockingQueue.take()` seems like what I need, but I just wrote a test program and I interrupting the `take()` method does not have any effect for as long as the queue is not empty. I already read about the poison pill method in the meantime but that approach isn't feasible in my situation because 1. the delivering thread isn't aware of what exactly it is adding on the queue and 2. the processing thread should not care about any remaining objects in the queue. I will investigate further on that single-threaded `Executor`.

Comment: Odd, the default implementation of `LinkedBlockingQueue` is definitely interruptable on `take()` even if the queue is non-empty. Looking at the source it does `ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly()` on a `take()` call no matter what the contents of the queue are (also testing it I have no issues interrupting with non-empty queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern (or rather, anti-pattern!) that you have created does not strictly constitute Double Checked Locking, which normally refers to the case where an object reference starts off null then is instantiated by the first thread that needs to reference it, with synchronization only after the null check. Up to Java 5, you couldn't strictly speaking implement this correctly in Java (though because of how most JVMs were implemented, you could accidentally get away with it). As of Java 5, you can use it, but it's essentially pointless. (You may be interested in an [article on double-checked locking in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/double_checked_locking.shtml) that I wrote a while ago which looks at this issue in more detail. The class-loader effectively has built-in synchronisation for rare cases where you do actually need something like DCL.)

Now, that's all kind of by the by. What you have here isn't really DCL strictly-speaking.

The problem that you do have is that **you're trying to mix paradigms**. The *raison d'être* of the Java concurrency library is generally to avoid low-level locking with synchronized and wait/notify. So what you should really do is simply use some flavour of BlockingQueue and use its built-in blocking behaviour. Again, among other examples might I refer you to some [material I have written on blocking queues](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/blockingqueue.shtml).

Comment: That seems clear to me. That is what I was thinking: DCL is about creating singleton objects in a multi-threaded environment, as I couldn't find any DCL (anti-pattern) examples without the singleton. As MarkoTopolnik also mentioned, the BlockingQueue interface is the way to go. I will adapt my code - it will be cleaner, more readable, and indeed and won't have to care about low-level synchronization. I accepted your answer as it is the most complete - it answers my original question and you provided the best alternative.

Comment: I have read Effective Java Ed. 2 by now and a lazy loaded singleton can easily be achieved by using an inner class holding a static field that would be your singleton. This works as class loading is synchronized in the JVM, thereby ensuring that the static field can only be initialized once, and the static field is initialized only when the inner class is accessed, effectively implementing the laziness. The singleton method can then just return InnerClass.STATIC_FIELD. It has a name: Initialization-on-demand holder idiom.

Comment: Yes, the usual way to implement a singleton is to let the class loader do the work. I referred specifically to your issue of using DCL in my answer. But if the question you meant to ask was "how do I implement a singleton class in Java", then as you say, the answer is generally to use a static final field that is initialised in the class's static code and let the class loader do the synchronisation work (since classes are lazily loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book by Brian Goetz, section 16.2.4 "Double-checked locking". It provides the explanation of why DCL is a wrong thing to do.

Comment: You are absolutely right about reading that book (I also want to lay my hands on "Effective Java"). I just should buy it.

Comment: I bought it several months ago, now in chapter 12. Thanks for your answer, I'm looking forward to chapter 16 now that I read your answer again.